# iOS: Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints

Tags: ios, constraints, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I've seen the common response to this question of not having constraints set up properly. However, I've worked through all of the ambiguities in Interface Builder, and all constraints seem OK. I'm not sure what to check next. I can't even tell where it is coming from. I'm not setting any constraints in code.

What can I do to figure out where it is coming form?
What can be the cause if Interface Builder doesn't report any ambiguities?

Here's the specific error:

```
2014-06-28 19:54:36.070 Prayer Feed[4497:60b] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x178290360 H:[UIImageView:0x13ee32490(20)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x1782904f0 UITableViewCellContentView:0x178166840.centerX == UIImageView:0x13ee32490.centerX + 62>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x178290540 H:|-(52)-[UIImageView:0x13ee32490]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x178166840 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x170286d60 h=--& v=--& H:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x178166840(247)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x178290360 H:[UIImageView:0x13ee32490(20)]>
```

I know the two place in code where I have a UIImageView constrained to 20x20, but again, IB tells me everything is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the part where the problem is:

```
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x170286d60 h=--& v=--& H:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x178166840(247)]>
```

This mask needs to be turned off.

I think that mask is off by default for IB elements that have constraints. So I assume you made something in code. You can turn it off in code like this:

```
contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO
```

If this is really all IB only then I would like to know what code you use around creating table cells.

Comment: This is helpful, though I'm not quite there yet. It appears that the third party control [MMDrawerController](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController) from Mutual Mobile is the culprit. I removed that control from my project temporarily and the problem went away. That, or it's one my cells being shown in that controller--which is more likely the case. :(

Comment: Sure enough, adding that line in my table cell subclass makes the error go away, but now my cells don't look right. They need the constraint. I'll have to look into this a little more. I'm new to constraints, so looks like I need to do some more reading. MMDrawerController is the one dictating that it the mask needs to be there. It's doing something with centering, and setting the mask to NO makes the content off center.

Comment: Turns out in one of the tableviewcell nibs for the side bar (MMDrawerController), the image view had an "Aligns Center X" constraint. I didn't realize that when I let IB "Add missing constraints". Removed that and constraints were still blue (good), re-ran, and voila, no more errors. Thanks, @Departamento B.